# HTML layout and CSS not appropriate after plugin alters page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert a sticky footer into my site but it's conflicting with a js script I'm using.
The script is

```
skel.init({
    prefix: 'css/style',
    resetCSS: true,
    boxModel: 'border',
    grid: {
        gutters: 50
    },
    breakpoints: {
        'mobile': {
            range: '-480',
            lockViewport: true,
            containers: 'fluid',
            grid: {
                collapse: true,
                gutters: 10
            }
        },
        'desktop': {
            range: '481-',
            containers: 1200
        },
        '1000px': {
            range: '481-1200',
            containers: 960
        }
    }
}, {
    panels: {
        panels: {
            navPanel: {
                breakpoints: 'mobile',
                position: 'left',
                style: 'reveal',
                size: '80%',
                html: '<div data-action="navList" data-args="nav"></div>'
            }
        },
        overlays: {
            titleBar: {
                breakpoints: 'mobile',
                position: 'top-left',
                height: 44,
                width: '100%',
                html: '<span class="toggle" data-action="togglePanel" data-args="navPanel"></span>' +
 '<span class="title" data-action="copyHTML" data-args="logo"></span>'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

the footer will remain at the top until the init.js script is removed, unfortunately though removing that removes the styling. I thing I've narrowed the issue down to somewhere within "breakpoints" but have no clue as to a fix.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: CSS and JavaScript cannot conflict. This is a matter of your CSS and HTML structure not ending suited to your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Either move `footer` outside `#skel-panels-pageWrapper` or set it to `position: fixed`. It's set absolutely as a child of `#skel-panels-pageWrapper`, which isn't full-height.

It may also work to set `#skel-panels-pageWrapper` to `position: absolute` and give it `bottom: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest scrapping that whole thing... you have just about the most simple setup possible so far, and you are already having major problems because that skeleton thing is so opinionated and you don't fully understand what it's doing. The css it's spitting out is insane and unnecessary. It's going to trip you up at every step of the way - at all of it's arbitrary break-points.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.next-closest-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Should get you in the right direction, but I would look at this pen.

http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/ziGbE

Comment: thanks for your reply, if I scrap the script completely I lose the responsive element required for mobile.,

Comment: It's really about 10 lines of code to make that one menu change.

Comment: I've decided to take your advise and scrap the script and use media queries which I do understand

Comment: Good for you! All these 'libraries' and 'frameworks' are just someone else's *mess* - that they want to share with you. Learning the languages instead of memorizing their "tricks" is going to be better int he long run. I have my set of rules, http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/zxmjgr  -- but trying to get other's to use them sounds like a waste of time.